# Why cannot we have constructor with name different from class names as long as they are unique

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

I understand that Java imposes a restriction that class name should be same as constructor name. Why is this restriction imposed? Why cannot I have a constructor of the class with a different name than class name as long as no constructor with the same name exists for any other class?

Comment: How would  you propose to designate a method as a constructor?

Comment: Because using the same name as the class is precisely how we indicate that a declaration is a constructor.  Also, it would cause confusion, which would break Java’s mission of code being as readable as possible.  You can always write static factory methods, such as [NumberFormat.getInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance%28%29).

Comment: One could argue that a static factory method *is* the Java idiom for a named constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we can have another name rather than the class name, You have to check whether it's already been used for any other class or not. To elaborate more consider the following example,

```
Person p1 = new Vehicle();
```

Now, In another class

```
MotorCycle m1 = new Vehicle(); // if you have used the same name then it will create a conflict for the compiler which implementation should be considered.
```

Now, think about the actual constructor naming conventions that if you use the same as for Class name, it's easier and also makes sense.

```
Person p1 = new Person();
MotorCycle m1 = new MotorCycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Java cannot "see" other classes, it only cares about the one class when it's compiling it.

Also, if the constructor is named something other than the class name, it cannot be found and it doesn't make any sense anyway. Imagine doing this:

```
Person person = new Robot();
```

where `Robot` would be a constructor in `Person`. It just doesn't make any sense to humans or the compiler!

Comment: It does make sense to have Robot() as constructor name , Python constructor is __init__ which does not have a class name.

Comment: This isn't python. Nor does python have the same design ideals as java.

Comment: Anyway, init is standard in python, just like the class name is in java.

Comment: Just to clarify the python argument: `__init__` is not the constructor in python, `__new__` is, but the convention is the same as in Java. `class Person: def __init__(self)` etc is still initialized as `person = Person()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the convention of having the same name for the class and it's construcors was considered useful. Alternatively the language would have to be extended with a keyword ( `constructor` ?), method name conflicts resolved etc...

Can you share a use case that benefits from arbitrary named construcor method?

Comment: I do not see any benefits , but does give flexibility to the programmer. Also constructor name even if different from class name , don't need keyword ; since constructor does not return anything (not even void) : during runtime , it can be identified.

Answer (score 0):

**This convention is for programming ease, constructor chaining and consistency in the language.**

For example, consider a scenario where you want to use Scanner class, 
now *what if the JAVA developers named the constructor as xyz!*

Then how will you get to know that you need to write :

*Scanner scObj = new xyz(System.in) ;*

which could've have been really weird, right!
Or, rather you might have to reference a huge manual to check constructor name of each class so as to get object created, which is again meaningless if you could have a solution of the problem by just naming constructors same as that of the class.

Secondly, the constructor is itself created by the compiler if you don't explicitly provide it, then what could be the best name for constructor could automatically be chosen by the compiler so it is clear to the programmer! Obviously, the best choice is to keep it the same as that of the class.

Thirdly, you may have heard of constructor chaining, then while chaining the calls among the constructors, how the compiler will know what name you have given to the constructor of the chained class!
Obviously, the solution to the problem is again same, KEEP NAME OF THE CONSTRUCTOR SAME AS THAT OF THE CLASS.

Thanks for Asking.